# Removing Duplicated Entries: Delete a entry that has 2 the same column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have this table called **bag**:

```
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
| bag_id | chara_id | item_id | item_qty |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|      1 |        1 |       2 |       22 |
|      2 |        1 |       1 |       55 |
|      3 |        3 |       1 |        2 |
|      6 |        3 |       4 |        2 |
|      7 |        4 |       4 |        2 |
|      8 |        5 |       4 |        2 |
|      9 |        6 |       4 |        2 |
|     10 |        1 |       5 |        1 |
|     11 |        1 |       2 |        1 |
|     12 |        1 |       2 |        1 |
|     13 |        1 |       2 |        1 |
|     14 |        1 |       8 |        1 |
|     15 |        1 |       6 |        1 |
|     16 |        1 |       8 |        1 |
|     17 |        1 |       6 |        1 |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
```

the relationship goes as 1 chara = many item
now i dont want 1 chara = many duplicated item.

how can i make a query that delete's the duplicated values?
like chara_id: 1 has 3 duplicated item_id: 2 
i want to delete the other 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join table `bag` with a subquery which gets the minimum `bag_id` for every combination of `chara_ID` and `item_ID`. Records that have null values on any fields on the subquery are the records that will be deleted.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    bag a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  chara_ID, item_ID, MIN(bag_ID) min_ID
            FROM    bag
            GROUP   BY chara_ID, item_ID
        ) b ON  a.bag_ID = b.min_ID AND
                a.chara_ID = b.chara_ID AND
                a.item_ID = b.item_ID
WHERE   b.min_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31cef4/3)

Comment: may i ask another noob question? :)

Comment: what question do you want to ask?

Comment: i put it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351292/mysql-query-insert-if-entry-is-duplicate-otherwise-update-the-existing-row-valu/16351369?noredirect=1#16351369 @JW

Answer (score 2):

Not the best way to do it. But the below should definetly work:

```
Delete from Bag 
where bag_id 
         not in (
                 select min(bag_id) from bag a, 
                    (select chara_id, item_id 
                        from bag group by chara_id, item_id 
                            having count(*) > 1) b 
                 where a.chara_id = b.chara_id and a.item_id = b.item_id 
                 UNION
                 select bag_id from bag a, 
                    (select chara_id, item_id 
                        from bag group by chara_id, item_id 
                            having count(*) = 1) b 
                 where a.chara_id = b.chara_id and a.item_id = b.item_id
         )
```