# MySQL Query: insert if entry is duplicate otherwise update the existing row values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a table called **bag**(again):

```
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
| bag_id | chara_id | item_id | item_qty |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|      1 |        1 |       2 |       22 |
|      2 |        1 |       1 |       55 |
|      3 |        3 |       1 |        2 |
|      6 |        3 |       4 |        2 |
|      7 |        4 |       4 |        2 |
|      8 |        5 |       4 |        2 |
|      9 |        6 |       4 |        2 |
|     10 |        1 |       5 |        1 |
|     14 |        1 |       8 |        1 |
|     15 |        1 |       6 |        1 |
|     18 |        1 |       4 |        1 |
|     19 |        1 |       3 |        1 |
|     29 |        8 |       1 |        1 |
|     30 |        8 |       7 |        1 |
|     33 |        6 |       2 |        1 |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
```

and i have this **SQL Statement**:

```
INSERT INTO bag(bag_id, chara_id, item_id, item_qty)VALUES(NULL, :id, :item_id,1)
```

after asking how to delete duplicates
wat i want to do next(to further restrict duplicates)is when a user buys an item already existing in his bag it increase the item_qty by 1 instead.

**like:**

```
if chara_id = exist and item_id exist 
   item_qty = item_qty + 1
else
   #..normal insert
```

if i use:

```
INSERT INTO bag(bag_id, chara_id, item_id)VALUES(NULL, 1, 2)
```

it should not insert but update the item_qty to 23 because that entry is already existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

but before it will work, you need to have an unique constraint on the table. If you don't have a unique constraint yet, based on your example you are checking on two columns if the values already exists,

```
ALTER TABLE bag ADD CONSTRAINT tb_unique UNIQUE (chara_id, item_id)
```

Once it has been implemented, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will not work.

```
INSERT INTO bag(chara_id, item_id, item_qty)
VALUES(1, 2, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_qty = item_qty + 1
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: i have just done that a while ago, and it seems to be working fine :) thanks again, i am confused though why mysql is returning 2 rows inserted. : )

Comment: I am also seeing "2 rows inserted" but it seems that only one row is actually being inserted. Is this a phpMyAdmin bug? using 4.4.12

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: ive read it, used it but it seems to be just inserting not updating even if an entry is existing

Comment: then you need to set a unique key on the combination of chara_id and item_id

Comment: wait,.. how do i do that i only know how to set a unique undex.